# XBAP application with activex component

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, com, activex, xbap

I created a Full Trust ClickOnce XBAP application that refers to com dll.
This dll is referenced in the app.manifest in this way:

```
<file name="MyLib.dll">
    <typelib tlbid="{YYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYY}" version="1.0" helpdir="" />
    <comClass description="My ActiveX" clsid="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX}"   
    tlbid="{YYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYY}"/>
</file>
```

When I run my app (locally) from the publishing html page, I see the error 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG), but if I manually register the dll in the running temp folder (Documents and Settings\Rick\Impostazioni locali\Apps\2.0\XXXXXXX) my app works fine. I dont want to run regsvr32 from my app because it requires administrative rights.

thanks to all,
Riccardo

Comment: i have also put my dll in the application references and set to "isolated", the manifest is correctly created, but it doesn't work...